# Dynamic TSQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a dynamic T-SQL query and running into an error.

I have removed everything except a single var and I still get the error when trying to run the query.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[empowermentFetchSubmissions2]
@category INT=NULL
AS
DECLARE @sSQL AS NVARCHAR (3000), 
@Where AS NVARCHAR (1000) = '';
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN
        SET @sSQL = 'SELECT   A.[submissionID],
                             A.[subEmpID],
                             A.[nomineeEmpID],
                             CONVERT (VARCHAR (10), A.[submissionDate], 101) AS submissionDate,
                             A.[situation],
                             A.[task],
                             A.[action],
                             A.[result],
                             A.[timestamp],
                             A.[statusID],
                             A.[approver],
                             A.[approvalDate],
                             B.[FirstName] + " " + B.[LastName] AS nomineeName,
                             B.[ntid] AS nomineeNTID,
                             B.[qid] AS nomineeQID,
                             C.[FirstName] + " " + C.[LastName] AS submitName,
                             C.[ntid] AS submitNTID,
                             D.[categoryName]
                    FROM     empowermentSubmissions AS A
                             INNER JOIN
                             empTable AS B
                             ON A.[nomineeEmpID] = B.[empID]
                             INNER JOIN
                             empTable AS C
                             ON A.[subEmpID] = C.[empID]
                             INNER JOIN
                             empowermentCategories AS D
                             ON A.[categoryID] = D.[catID]';
        IF (@category) IS NOT NULL
            SET @Where = @Where + ' AND A.[categoryID] = @_category';
        IF LEN(@Where) > 0
            SET @sSQL = @sSQL + 'WHERE ' + RIGHT(@Where, LEN(@Where) - 3);
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sSQL, N'@_category', @_category = @category;
    END
END
```

The error I get when running this is :

> Incorrect syntax near ')'. Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 28 An
>   expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'A'.

Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Are those double quotes or two single quotes in the nomineeName and submitName fields?  They should be two single quotes.

Comment: They are double quotes - Single quotes surround the `SET` and dont like when those are single..

Comment: I changed to single like so `B.[FirstName] + '' '' + B.[LastName] AS nomineeName,` and got the same error

Comment: You might need to remove space before ' AND A.[categoryID] = @_category'

Comment: From what you posted I don't see why you need to use dynamic sql for this at all.

Comment: @SeanLange there will be about 15 different filter options - I just wanted to make sure one worked first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code to the point where I think it will work. There were 3 problems I found by commenting out your execute line and putting a `print @ssql` before it. Then executed the stored procedure. First problem was the quotes. I changed them to single quotes. Next a new line for the `WHERE` where it was on the same line as the `ON`. Last issue was you weren't trimming enough off of the `WHERE` and it left the letter D.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[empowermentFetchSubmissions2]
@category INT=NULL
AS
DECLARE @sSQL AS NVARCHAR (3000), 
@Where AS NVARCHAR (1000) = '';
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN
        SET @sSQL = 'SELECT   A.[submissionID],
                             A.[subEmpID],
                             A.[nomineeEmpID],
                             CONVERT (VARCHAR (10), A.[submissionDate], 101) AS submissionDate,
                             A.[situation],
                             A.[task],
                             A.[action],
                             A.[result],
                             A.[timestamp],
                             A.[statusID],
                             A.[approver],
                             A.[approvalDate],
                             B.[FirstName] + '' '' + B.[LastName] AS nomineeName,
                             B.[ntid] AS nomineeNTID,
                             B.[qid] AS nomineeQID,
                             C.[FirstName] + '' '' + C.[LastName] AS submitName,
                             C.[ntid] AS submitNTID,
                             D.[categoryName]
                    FROM     empowermentSubmissions AS A
                             INNER JOIN
                             empTable AS B
                             ON A.[nomineeEmpID] = B.[empID]
                             INNER JOIN
                             empTable AS C
                             ON A.[subEmpID] = C.[empID]
                             INNER JOIN
                             empowermentCategories AS D
                             ON A.[categoryID] = D.[catID]';
        IF (@category) IS NOT NULL
            SET @Where = @Where + ' AND A.[categoryID] = @_category';
        IF LEN(@Where) > 0
            SET @sSQL = @sSQL + '
            WHERE ' + RIGHT(@Where, LEN(@Where) - 4);
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sSQL, N'@_category', @_category = @category;
    END
END
```

Here is what your code was printing originally if you want to see the problems.

```
SELECT   A.[submissionID],
                             A.[subEmpID],
                             A.[nomineeEmpID],
                             CONVERT (VARCHAR (10), A.[submissionDate], 101) AS submissionDate,
                             A.[situation],
                             A.[task],
                             A.[action],
                             A.[result],
                             A.[timestamp],
                             A.[statusID],
                             A.[approver],
                             A.[approvalDate],
                             B.[FirstName] + " " + B.[LastName] AS nomineeName,
                             B.[ntid] AS nomineeNTID,
                             B.[qid] AS nomineeQID,
                             C.[FirstName] + " " + C.[LastName] AS submitName,
                             C.[ntid] AS submitNTID,
                             D.[categoryName]
                    FROM     empowermentSubmissions AS A
                             INNER JOIN
                             empTable AS B
                             ON A.[nomineeEmpID] = B.[empID]
                             INNER JOIN
                             empTable AS C
                             ON A.[subEmpID] = C.[empID]
                             INNER JOIN
                             empowermentCategories AS D
                             ON A.[categoryID] = D.[catID]WHERE D A.[categoryID] = @_category
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the double quotes to two single quotes:

```
B.[FirstName] + '' '' + B.[LastName] AS nomineeName,
C.[FirstName] + '' '' + C.[LastName] AS submitName,
```

EDIT:
You also need a space in front of WHERE on this line:

```
SET @sSQL = @sSQL + ' WHERE ' + RIGHT(@Where, LEN(@Where) - 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not stripping off enough characters from the start of your @Where variable, if you want to take ' AND ' off it. That's 5 characters, not three.

In any case it's unnecessary since there's only going to be one condition in the WHERE clause (so you could just do away with the AND in the first place, rather than putting it in and then stripping it out again), but I assume you plan for this to get more complicated?

Comment: Yeah there is going to be a lot more pieces to it but needed to get it working with 1 first

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you could also do

```
@Where AS NVARCHAR (1000) = ' (1=1) ';
```

Then you can just append any number of "AND ..." as you like without further string processing.

Comment: What do you mean "Further string processing" ?

Comment: I just mean you can then use `@Where` instead of `RIGHT(@Where, LEN(@Where) - 3)`. One less chance for errors.